# One parent table, two children tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following problem that I'm trying to model in an API-only Rails app. A `Business` can have many `Programs`. A `Program` has a number of basic attributes. However, there are many types of said `Program`, let's say `ProgramA` and `ProgramB` and so on, each with its own attributes.

I will need to query all the programs that belong to a `Business` and return it to the client along with the "type" of the program so it can be properly parsed.

How can I model this relationship in Rails 5?

Comment: Can you give an example of what your models look like? When you say there are multiple types of `Program`'s, I'm imagining single table inheritence (A `Program` table with a `type` column, that would be `A`, `B`, `C`, and so-on). The answer to this question depends on how you set that up

Comment: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html for STI, here's a good medium article to determine if STI is really what you want https://medium.freecodecamp.org/single-table-inheritance-vs-polymorphic-associations-in-rails-af3a07a204f2

Comment: @Asthmatic Wouldn't this result in a lot of null/undefined values in the table? In my case, each of those subclasses have a large number of unique attributes, a few even have associations with other models.

Comment: Right, which is why i wanted more information in your question. In that case you should have two different tables `ProgramA` and `ProgramB`, have some sort of identifier in each (usually self.name is enough), and have a scope in `Business` that handles both together https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the common STI inheritance pattern:

```
# app/models/business.rb
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base 
    has_many :programs 
end

# app/models/program.rb
class Program < ActiveRecord::Base 
    belongs_to :business 
    self.inheritance_column = :type 

    #Defining subclasses
    def self.types
      %w(A B C)
    end
end

# app/models/a.rb
class A < Program; end

# app/models/b.rb
class B < Program; end

# app/models/c.rb
class C < Program; end
```

You have two tables, the `businesses` table and the `programs` table. The programs table has a column `type` which corresponds to the type of program, which has the same other properties as every other type. Then each type of program can have specific attributes that only it has. Rails and activerecord handle this automagically, with a few caveats that you can find online.

This is a good way to go if your programs share a lot of attributes, not as good if they don't.

Some reading material: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html

Comment: Wouldn't this result in a lot of null/undefined values in the table? In my case, each of those subclasses have a large number of unique attributes, a few even have associations with other models.